# Wordpress custom admin panel

Tags: wordpress, admin

I am developing a bespoke Wordpress theme including a custom admin section inside the Wordpress CMS.

I have been looking for inspiration from exisiting admin panels and have found exactly what I am looking for (but not for jobs) http://demo.wpjobboard.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpjb/job

I have managed to create my own panel section and sub menu.

- My Site Options

  - News
  - Events

When the user selects News or Events I need Wordpress to list the news and events to be shown on the site. I am confused as to where the news and events data would be stored though.

In a custom php cms I would have events/news tables and list the data out for these in a html table. For Wordpress would it be in the Wordpress posts table or in a custom table?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about how to add admin menu and call a function to show the page ?

Comment: I have rephrased my question slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want is a section with optional theme settings. It's a bit of work to explain how to do it here, [but I found this tutorial which is extremely helpful](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/).